# why to use resultset!=null does it check for null

Tags: java, jdbc

I have following code

```
if (rs != null)
{
  out.println("result set has got something");
  while (rs.next())
  { 
    //I am processing result set now
  }
}
else
{
  out.println("result set is empty");
}
```

Even though rs is null it is printing **"resultset has got something"**. Why is it happening like that and  how can I check for empty result set?

Comment: clean the app and retry again, also put a watch on rs

Comment: You seem to not understand what `null` is/means. `rs` is not `null` if it prints that; it's holding a reference to a `ResultSet` object. `null` has nothing to do with an empty result set.

Comment: @JigarJoshi yes i did even though i am facing same problem .i got this code from http://www.coderanch.com/t/296373/JDBC/java/do-you-check-Result-set even they are facing same issue they gave lot of solutions but i didn't get

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could check it with:

```
if(rs != null && rs.next()) {
    out.println("result set has got something");
    do {
        // do what you have to do
    } while (rs.next());
} else {
    out.println("result set is empty");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JDBC ResultSet objects returned as a query result are never null please read the javadoc. So the way you are checking is wrong. You can use `ResultSet.next()` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

A `ResultSet` object maintains a cursor pointing to its current row of data - Unless your calling method has no guarantee the passed Resultset is generated by executing a statement via a specific query, then handling the Null Pointer using;

```
if(rs !=null && rs.next())
{
 ..
}
```

is essential -but if you're handling

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(..);
```

then no need performing Null point checking, just go straight to the point and ask ResultSet if it holds data;

```
String name=null;
while (rs.next()) 
{
 name =rs.getString(1);
}
```

and then handle values like this;

```
if(name !=null && name.length()>0)
{
 ..        
}
```

Comment: if i no need to check null value then how can i check for empty values it may create null exception

Answer (score 0):

For record sets, its always better to use ternary operators provided by Java.
For eg:

Say you want to set the name to the user object pojo.

```
myUser.setName(null != recordSet.getString("name") ? recordSet.getString("name") : "Guest");
```

Hope this helps.